# What's the proper way of using Javascript's window.opener?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, window.opener

I've created a popup window and in it I'd like to use a function I've created in the parent window.  I've tried using window.opener.parentFunction() but to know avail.  Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Here's what my code looks like.

```
function parentFunction(){
alert('testing');
}


function print(){
var new_win = window.open('','name','height=400,width=500');
var output = "<html><head></head><body><table>\n";


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
output += "<td onclick='window.opener.parentFunction()'>"+i+"</td>";
}

output += "</table></body></html>\n";
new_win.document.write(output);
}
```

*Got it working.  Thanks guys.

Comment: In the new window, is `window.opener` null? Is `parentFunction` visible at the global scope? How is `print()` bound? Are you sure that `this.getCols()` is defined? What about `years`? The code you posted is not complete.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I didn't include all my code.  I just edited it to make it simpler.

Comment: your code now work as-is.. do you still have any question or problem? If not please mention that it's now fixed in the question body as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code. I've put together a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7DYpr/).

#### HTML

```
<button id="clickMe">Click me</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {

    function parentFunction() {
        alert('testing');
    }

    window.parentFunction = parentFunction;

    var years = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    function print() {
        var new_win = window.open('', 'name', 'height=400,width=500');
        //var cols = this.getCols();
        var cols = 2;
        var output = "<html><head></head><body><table>";
        var cell_count = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
            if (cell_count === 1) {
                output += "<tr>";
            }
            output += "<td onclick='window.opener.parentFunction();'>" + years[i] + "</td>";
            cell_count++;
            // end the row if we've generated the expected number of columns
            // or if we're at the end of the array
            if (cell_count > cols || i === years.length - 1) {
                output += "</tr>\n";
                cell_count = 1;
            }
        }
        output += "</table></body></html>";
        new_win.document.write(output);
    }

    document.getElementById('clickMe').onclick = print;
};
```

- `years` was not defined
- `this.getCols()` was not defined
- `parentFunction` was (probably) not visible at the `window` scope

Comment: @Matt `window.addEvent` - is this a library?

Comment: @Šime: that's just what jsfiddle does behind the scenes by default - I guess MooTools? I threw it in there mostly to show how `parentFunction` might not be visible in the global scope, but you're right, that ain't vanilla JS. Will tweak.

Comment: Exactly what it looks like. Assigns whatever value `parentFunction` evaluates to (in this case, a function) to a property of the `window` object, also named `parentFunction`.

Comment: I was actually able to see it working without that line: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/Nvgq9/ so it's probably something else you changed that fixed the problem..

Comment: @Shadow That depends on the options in jsfiddle. If you use "no wrap" then `parentFunction` is a global function. If you use onDomReady or onLoad then it is a local to the ready/load handler.

Comment: Thanks @Šime wasn't aware of this, always selecting "no wrap (head)". Question is what is the behavior in "real life" JS, without jsFiddle? As far as I know, any top level function is global.. isn't it?

Comment: @Shadow Yes, top level = global. In the browser, all functions that are not nested inside other functions, are global = properties of the `window` object.

Comment: @Šime so how come the original code didn't work? As far as I can see it's a top level function. :/

Comment: @Shadow: because the OP's code was not the full picture of the actual code.

Comment: @Shadow Depends on how and when you run `window.open`. In Chrome, if you run it immediately, Chrome's pop-up blocker will block the new window. However, if you run it `onclick`, then Chrome will show the window (as your demo demonstrates).

Comment: Thanks Matt. :) @Šime - I think the new window did open well but didn't invoke the parent function when clicking a cell in the popup window. At least that's how I understand the original question.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, you're right. OP's original code probably threw an error on `this.getCols()`... or maybe `years` wasn't defined? Only OP knows.